# Pass a value into a thread from a while loop

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I have a while loop that gets a value and calls a function in a new thread with the that information. The problem is I can't get it to give me a new address for that information in each iteration of the while loop. So the while loop ends up modifying the information being used by the running thread.

Here is an excerpt from my code. The printf statement reveals that the address of string is the same, and is therefore overwritten while the thread is running

```
    char * string = (char *) malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(string, item);
    if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printWithDelay, &string)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Dispatched thread for %s at %p\n", string, &string);
    free(string);
```

I have also tried without malloc and that doesn't work either. Is there any way to do this?

Before you ask, yes I am a student, and yes this is for an assignment. However, the assignment didn't ask me to do any of this. We aren't even supposed to know threads exist yet. I'm just trying to push myself to go beyond the bounds of the assignment and am having a bit of trouble. I'm trying to do sleepsort as a joke to the grader whom I know personally.

Full code and assignment description here: http://hastebin.com/cetepakevu.c

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is to remove the `free`. Another option is to have the thread call `free` when it's done with the memory. The final option is to have `main` call `pthread_join` to wait for the thread to finish, and then call `free`.

Comment: I have tried it with and without the free. I have also tried it with char string[1024]; instead.

Comment: Oh, in the call to `pthread_create`, the `&string` should be `string`. You're passing the address of your pointer, which is always the same.

Comment: 1) A `while` loop is a statement,  it cannot "pass a value into a thread" 2) There is no `while` (or any other) loop shown 3) See [ask].

Comment: The full code is available in the original post

Comment: @larperdoodle has user3386109 resolved your issue? The other thing you should do is move the `free` into the function `printWithDelay`, as otherwise you might free the buffer before you can actually use it.

Comment: `strcpy` is complete *crap*. *Never* call it. *Ever*. Use `strncpy` and stick a 0 at the end to make sure it is null terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your present `pthread_create` call, you have a race condition because you're passing `&string` instead of `string` (i.e. you're passing a pointer to the main thread's `string` variable instead of its *contents*). Thus, two [or more] child threads could end up using the same string buffer.

Also, you have the main thread doing the `free` on the string. This must be done in the child thread. A `free` works globally for all threads, so main does the `free` before the child can use the data [or gets it yanked out from under itself shortly thereafter].

Further, a "minor" problem that is a consequence of that: Because `main` does the `malloc` and the `free` [assuming no child thread does any `malloc`], it is likely that `malloc` will always return the same value. So, all child threads could be using the same string buffer, race condition or not.

On the other hand, if a child thread does a `malloc` for something else, it is now racing against the use of `string` [already allocated but freed] and the new allocation. Thus, someone holding/using a prior value for `string` could cause heap corruption [and/or segfault] if either of the two areas is written to in the "right" way, because the `malloc/heap` link pointers may be in the middle of a different allocation that overlaps.

---

Here's what I *think* you have [because you didn't show the child function]:

```
void
main_thread(void)
{

    while (1) {
        char *string = (char *) malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));

        strcpy(string, item);

        // BUG: race condition -- on the second loop, string can be changed
        // before thread 1 has a chance to dereference it, so thread 1
        // could end up using thread 2's string (or thread 3's ...)
        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printWithDelay, &string)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // BUG: child must do the free
        printf("Dispatched thread for %s at %p\n", string, &string);
        free(string);
    }
}

void *
printWithDelay(void *arg)
{
    char **strptr = arg;
    char *string;

    // BUG: this is the race condition -- we can get our string or
    // if we're delayed, we'll get the string for the next thread, so
    // we'd both use the same address
    string = *strptr;

    // use string ...

    return (void *) 0;
}
```

---

Here's the corrected code:

```
void
main_thread(void)
{

    while (1) {
        char *string = (char *) malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));

        strcpy(string, item);

        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printWithDelay, string)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

void *
printWithDelay(void *arg)
{
    char *string = arg;

    // use string ...

    free(string);

    return (void *) 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a common pattern: Allocate a chunk of memory. Fill it with data. Create a thread, passing it a pointer to the chunk you allocated. Let the thread free the chunk when it's done with it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, when done correctly, it's quite useful [and elegant in its simplicity]. For my own code, I usually allocate a "task control" struct. Then, I may alloc more things and fill the struct with their pointers and pass the struct pointer. So, many things can be passed. The child reverses the process at the end. IIRC, this is like the third or fourth question I've answered that had a virtually identical race condition. It's not necessarily obvious to someone just starting out with multithreaded code, so, no harm no foul.

Answer (score 0):

Though `pthread_create()` takes a `void *` for it's `arg`, you can pass by value by casting. I haven't verified this however this answer seems to do what you want. [pthread_create: Passing argument by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090755/pthread-create-passing-argument-by-value)

I think the best thing would be to consider a different thread api (or language) or simply write a clone function and pass the cloned variable's address.

Comment: Also not sure but you may have to treat the arg's address as the variable in the thread, and the size of the variable or type musn't be larger than `void *`. Kind of a c hack to pass by reference by the sounds of it.

Comment: The size of the buffer is `1024 * sizeof(char)`, so passing by value is not going to work. `string` is already a pointer, so it can be passed to `pthread_create` as it already is and be a pass by pointer.

Comment: Hmm inside the thread `arg` is at a new address so we should find a unique `&arg` inside the thread. However I can see no way to control `&arg+1` which is created at runtime or by the compiler (?) inside the thread. I can only conclude as Paul Rooney did, that there is no way to pass the string into `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't discussing the unrelated issue with thread contention. I had thought about how to pass the string by value somehow. If you had a void** (a pointer of type void *) who's values were void's which could represent single chars; I thought maybe this would be a way to pass the sting.

Comment: But I realized that it wouldn't work. Inside the thread function arg would have been copied, however the address after it would not have.

Comment: basically you get one single void * size to work with.